# Deserialize Nested JSON into classes/objects, in turn - serialize it back into string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here's my goal, I want to retrieve JSON data from a source, deserialize into objects, filter out objects based on value, and finally serialize it back into JSON string format. Here's (an example) what I have for JSON data:

```
[  
   {  
      "property":"prop1",
      "status" : {
         status1: "A",
         status2: -1,
         status3: "Success", 
      },
      "offlist":[  
         {  
            "description":"description blah",
            "type":"F",
            "values":{  
               "value1":30.0,
               "value2":0.0
            }
         },
         {  
            "description":"description blah",
            "type":"F",
            "values":{  
               "value1":30.0,
               "value2":0.0
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "property":"prop2",
      "status" : {
         status1: "A",
         status2: -1,
         status3: "Success", 
      },
      "offlist":[  
         {  
            "description":"description blah",
            "type":"Q",
            "values":{  
               "value1":30.0,
               "value2":0.0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here's my classes:

```
public class offerModel {
    public List<offlist> offlist { get; set; }
    public status statuses { get; set; }
    public string property{ get; set; }
}
public class offlist{
    public string description{ get; set; }
    public string type{ get; set; }
    public values values { get; set; }        
}
public class values{
    public double value1 { get; set; }
    public double value2{ get; set; }
}

public class statuses {
    public string status1 { get; set; }
    public double status2 { get; set; }
    public string status3 { get; set; }

}
public class RootObj {
    public List<offerModel> offModels { get; set; }
}
```

Upon attempt of deserializing into objects, I get a List of 5 objects back (Which is intended), but all those objects are null. See Below:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObj>>(jsonstring);
```

I then want to remove any 'offlist' objects with the 'type' value equaling 'F'.

After removing those, I then want to put back into JSON string format, which I believe would be very similar to below, I'm just not able to get it to deserialize in the correct fashion.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Let me know if I left any details out...

Comment: Try 'JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OffModel>>(jsonstring)' instead you JSON root object is a collection and not a collection of objects with collection field inside

Comment: Solve your first problem.  You are asking to deserialize a `List<RootObj>` when the json you have posted seems to represent a `List<offerModel>`. 
 How you end up with 5 null references in the resulting list isn't immediately apparent since your posted json appears to represent an array of **two** `offerModel`s.

Comment: Could be it is because of your json - status1..3, they are not strings, if this is supposed to be a legit json, it fails validation of one. (must be inside quotes)

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Deltics - Yes above shows only an array of 2 objects, as stated above "Here's (an example) what I have for JSON data:"... I wasn't going to put the whole JSON string in here. Just enough for you to understand where I was going. As far the the "Status" objects, you are correct on them needing to be inside quotations, I ultimately changed some verbiage for business purposes and forgot to add quotations back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change serialization to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<offerModel>>(data)`
and fix `offerModel` class property `statuses` to `public statuses status { get; set; }` to make your sample deserializable
If you want to keep a root object you can do next:

```
public class RootObj : List<offerModel>{}
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(data)
```

Comment: OMG I knew it was something stupid, Thank you ASpirin, much appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

**Deserialize nested JSON into Class. not on dictionary based but it's useful.**

Step 01: open the link [https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mIFA.png)

Step 02: copy your json file or contents.

Step 03: Open above link. copy contents and past in to left side and click on to JSON Parser button.

Step 04: Click on download button. Downloading the jsonformatter.txt file. Successfully download the file as jsonformatter.txt.

Step 05: Copy step 02 content and open url https://json2csharp.com/.Copy contents and past in to left side and click on to Convert button.

Step 06: In Scripting.

(A) Create myRootClass.cs file and copy and past down contents to your file.[[System.Serializable] it's used in unity 3d software c# scripting]

```
[System.Serializable]
public class myRootClass
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
   [System.Serializable]
    public class Status
   {
    public string status1 { get; set; }
    public int status2 { get; set; }
    public string status3 { get; set; }
   }
   [System.Serializable]
   public class Values
   {
    public double value1 { get; set; }
    public double value2 { get; set; }
   }
   [System.Serializable]
   public class Offlist
   {
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Values values { get; set; }
   }

   public class Root
  {
    public string property { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public List<Offlist> offlist { get; set; }
   }
}
```

(B) Read the jsonformatter.txt file.

```
// Read entire text file content in one string 
    string  textFilePath = "C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/jsonformatter.txt";//change path
    string jsontext = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(textFilePath);  
    Debug.Log("Read Json"+jsontext);// used Console.Writeline
```

(C) Convert string into C# and show the data.

```
  Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsontext); 
  
  Debug.Log("myDeserializedClass.property:- "+myDeserializedClass.property); //used Console.Writeline
 var offlists= myDeserializedClass.offlist; // used foreach and view data
```